# Is there any way to implement extend with proto3?

Tags: protocol-buffers

because there is no `extend` in `proto3`, so I combine the base message with `google.protobuf.Any` type message, but it's binary length is too long

.proto file

```
message TradeMessage {  
     google.protobuf.Any message = 1;  
     string code = 2;
}  
message Connect {
     int32 seq = 1;
     string appid = 2;
     string clientid = 3;
     string ver = 4;
}
...
```

.java file

```
TradeProtocol.Connect inner = TradeProtocol.Connect.newBuilder()
                    .setSeq(1)
                    .setAppid("test")
                    .build();

TradeProtocol.TradeMessage packet = TradeProtocol.TradeMessage.newBuilder()
                    .setMessage(Any.pack(inner))
                    .setCode(2)
                    .build();
```

service send packet to client, client can decode all message to base TradeMessage, the problem is the inner's length is 8 bytes, while packet's length is 56 bytes. the same function implement use `proto2`'s extend just ten more bytes, so is there any way to implement extend function in `proto3` or reduce the packet's length ? thanks

Answer (score 1):

One alternative is to use oneof:

```
message Connect {
     int32 seq = 1;
     string appid = 2;
     string clientid = 3;
     string ver = 4;
}

message TradeMessage {  
     string code = 1;
     oneof inner {
          Connect inner_connect = 2;
          SomeOtherMessage inner_other = 3;
          ...
     }
}
```

The encoded size will still be larger than with `extend`, but only by 1-2 bytes.